# using webrtc for audio broadcast

Tags: webrtc, http-live-streaming, live-streaming, janus

I'm trying to stream a microphone/audio to multiple clients.

- the broadcaster is a screenless raspberry, so I can't open a Webbrowser and click on "share mircophone"
- The clients will be using their smartphone to listen.
- the latency must be super low.

I did not find any WebRTC Demo that worked. All of them are either p2p or the scalable Broadcasting from muaz khan is only working for the initiator; not clients.

I came across Janus (which I didn't really understand what exactly this is doing) but I don't get how to install this and how to configure it.

**Is there any way to easily share the microphone's output via WebRTC?** Something like Apache hosting a simple website where the microphone audio is hosted on?

Thanks for all the ideas on how to solve it!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to easily share the microphone's output via WebRTC?

No.  There's nothing easy or simple about WebRTC.

> the broadcaster is a screenless raspberry, so I can't open a Webbrowser and click on "share mircophone"

This is the simplest option... running a browser.  Are you *sure* you need to actually allow it to access the audio device?

In the past, I've used a flag on Chromium to get around this problem.  I don't remember exactly what that flag was, but looking at [the list](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/), it might have been...

```
--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream
```

You might also be able to use `--enable-kiosk-mode`.

At a minimum, if you were to open the browser interactively and enable access, that page would get automatic access in the future.

> I did not find any WebRTC Demo that worked. All of them are either p2p

WebRTC *is* peer-to-peer, but remember that the "server" can be one of those "peers".

Finally, you can look into using GStreamer, but don't expect anything quick and easy.  https://github.com/centricular/gstwebrtc-demos